# Does V8 crash if it cannot allocate memory? Does this crash the entire process?

Tags: javascript, c++, exception, stl, v8

This question is similar to [one I recently asked about LLVM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38673770/200783).

V8 allocates JavaScript objects on a manually-managed heap, memory for which is ultimately obtained from mmap/VirtualAlloc (on Linux/Windows). However, for its internal data structures, V8 [uses C++ standard containers such as `std::vector`](https://github.com/v8/v8/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=std%20vector). If these containers need to allocate memory, but are unable to, they usually throw `std::bad_alloc`.

However, V8 [is compiled with -fno-exceptions](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/v8-users/ffdydgcdavM/rKiTQlzvAgAJ). If exceptions cannot be used, how does V8 handle the situation where the internal data structures are unable to allocate memory? Does it crash? If so, does this take down any process which embeds V8?

Comment: No, my browser uses "V8" as well as my node.js, as far as I've seen, the crashes go as far as the application containers goes.

Comment: Check out this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-users/n-dbQX1AvTM. BTW, even the Google C++ style guide says "We do not use C++ exceptions" https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Exceptions

Comment: @VladislavIvanishin only because of [legacy code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184115/google-c-style-guides-no-exceptions-rule-stl)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general even if your code is compiled with `-fno-exceptions` (then `new` won't throw `std::bad_alloc` but it will return `nullptr` instead) the standard C++ library libstdc++ is compiled with exceptions then `new` will still throw `std::bad_alloc` when you're running out-of-memory.

That said, seriously, when you're running out-of-memory to crash as fast as possible is (more often than not) the best thing you can do. If you need some some sort of reliability it's much easier to have a *monitor* process that will restart your application.

What V8 does? Obviously they overloaded `new` operator and when allocation fails (`malloc()` still returns `NULL`, of course) they call a *special* function to handle low memory conditions. It dumps some debug information, report this error (you may have a custom error handler) and then (if error handler returns) call `FATAL()` to quit the application.

Browse source code at [api.cc on GitHub](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/api.cc). From code, simply:

> When V8 cannot allocated memory FatalProcessOutOfMemory is called.
>   The default OOM error handler is called and execution is stopped.

Comment: _Obviously they overloaded `new` operator_ - do you know where in the code this overloaded operator is implemented?

Comment: Base allocator for _internal_ classes is in allocator.h. There you also find NewArray() used in their own Vector class (same behavior, call FatalProcessOutOfMemory() if malloc() returned null).